# What's an OCCI context and environment?

Tags: c++, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm exploring a piece of software making use of Oracle API and as far as I can see often object methods expect as an argument a "OCCI context" or a "OCCI environment" values.

An example is a constructor of an Account object:

```
Account( oracle::occi::Environment* env );
```

later overloaded with

```
Account( void* oraCtx );
```

I can understand that somehow they have to do with sort of a "connection handler", but I'd like to know more.

I googled around but I couldn't find anything clear enough for me, it seems every doc starts from the assumption you already know Oracle API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OCCI Environment` lets you define your own memory management functions which `OCCI` will later use.

When you create an `environment`, you pass the pointers to your own `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`:

```
static Environment * createEnvironment(Mode mode = DEFAULT,
   void *ctxp = 0,
   void *(*malocfp)(void *ctxp, size_t size) = 0,
   void *(*ralocfp)(void *ctxp, void *memptr, size_t newsize) = 0,
   void (*mfreefp)(void *ctxp, void *memptr) = 0);
```

`Context` is just a pointer to an `Environment` that is passed to these functions when `OCCI` calls them.